# No output after entry check with PHP isset

Tags: php, isset

I'm experimenting with forms and I can't tell why the cod below wont echo out the supposed result. Why am doing wrong and how do I get it to echo out user input.

```
<?php

//way to tell if the form has been submitted (If form not submitted, display form again.)
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){

?>

    <form method="post" action="" />
    <input type="text" name="city" />
    <input type="submit">

</form>

<?php
//Process input
}
else
{

// Retrieve information from form submission.

$username = $_POST['city'];
echo "Your name is $username.";
}
?>
```

Comment: You have no element named `submit`.

Comment: @chris85 Do you mean for the submit?

Comment: Yes, you are testing if `$_post['submit']` is set. You have no element named that so it will never be set. Also the `post` should be capitalized. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give your submit button a name property:

```
//way to tell if the form has been submitted (If form not submitted, display form again.)
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){

?>

    <form method="post" action="" />
    <input type="text" name="city" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>

<?php
//Process input
}
else
{

// Retrieve information from form submission.

$username = $_POST['city'];
echo "Your name is $username.";
}
?>
```